# Naming convention for methods that add to given parameter

Tags: java, coding-style

I provide an interface that makes an object to the content of a message.

```
public interface MessageContent {
  void addContent(Message message);
}
```

The Problem is that if methods starting with "`add`" in java, they're usually adding the parameter to the object (`this`). In my case the method adds the object (`this`) to the given parameter.

Is there a naming convention for such methods?

Comment: I don't know that there is a specific naming convention, but either way, this seems like a very strange design ...

Comment: I doubt that there will be any "convention" for this. It's all about making the method name as **meaningful** and **intuitive** as possible. And documenting it accordingly.

Comment: `putContent()` or `setContent()` .. may not be a convention.

Comment: I would call the method `addTo`.

Comment: addTo is a good one. Thank you